# Storing products bought into another model order_products

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

**Updated

I have the following models:

product.rb

```
class Product

belongs_to :user
has_many :line_items
has_many :orders, :through => :order_products
has_many :order_products
```

lineitem.rb

```
class LineItem

belongs_to :product
belongs_to :cart
belongs_to: order
```

order.rb

```
class Order

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :product
has_many :purchases
has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :orders, :through => :order_products
has_many :order_products

accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_products
```

order_product.rb

```
class OrderProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order
    belongs_to :product
end
```

order_controller.rb

```
if @order.save

  if @order.purchase
    Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
    session[:cart_id] = nil
```

The above are my association for the models. I have a big problem in storing multiple product_id from line_items after the cart has been purchased.

I believe there should be codes after if@order.purchase for it to work. How am I suppose to store the order_id and product_id into order_products table.

Can anyone assist me on this?

Appreciate any help here. Thanks

Comment: when you say place_id you mean product_id?

Comment: The first thing I would suggest here is to add `has_many :order_products` to `Product` and `Order` models. As you are trying to use a `has_many through` association without defining the association to be used as `through`.

Comment: Hi there, sorry i have made the necessary adjustments. However i still face the problem in storing the relevant product_ids which are purchase by a user to order_products table. Any idea on how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might benefit from learning about [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), as well as how [`foreign_keys`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) work with ActiveRecord

---

**Foreign Keys**

If you set up your ActiveRecord associations correctly, you'll be able to call something like `@product.line_items` from a single call

[ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) (& relational databsaes in general) work off `foreign_keys`, which are basically a reference to a model's id in another table. When you say you want to input `order_id` in another table, what you really need to look at is how to get ActiveRecord to put the correct foreign key into the record

The reason why I'm writing this is because if you can appreciate how ActiveRecord works, you'll be in a much stronger position to fix your problem

---

**Accepts_Nested_Attributes_For**

I believe the function that will help you is `accepts_nested_attributes_for` - which basically allows you to save another model's data through your current model

It works like this:

```
#/app/models/order.rb
class Order

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :product
has_many :purchases
has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :orders, :through => :order_products
has_many :order_products

accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_products
```

This means that if you send the appropriate nested attributes to this model, it will process `:order_products` for you

To do this, you need to add this to your form & controller:

```
#app/controllers/orders_controller.rb
def new
    @order = Order.new
    @order.order_products.build
end

private
def strong_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:standard_params,  order_products_attributes: [:name]  )
end


#app/views/orders/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :order_products do |product| %>
         <%= product.text_field :name %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help! However, nothing was stored into order_products even though I have added those that you have identify

Comment: Can you re-post your code? Also, your log of the request which was sent (nested_attributes are hard to get right)

Comment: Hi, I have added the accepts_nested_attribute into the order model. However, now what i need is to pass order_id and product_id that is derive from line_item to be included into order_products table. Hope it helps. Thanks